Multiprocessing with multiple class objects
I have different python classes and all of them having a method called push. What I am trying to is

Create multiple class objects one from each class
Call push method
All these methods should execute in parallel
Log messages coming from push method as and when its complete
Wait for all the methods to complete and exit scrip

I have tried multiple ways using
    #from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    def push_wrapper(obj):
        obj.push()
    
    
    class_objects=[class1_obj1,class2_obj2,class3_obj3]
    with Pool(processes=max_thread_count) as pool:
        pool.map(push_wrapper, class_objects)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

With this I am getting this error

raise TypeError(f"cannot pickle {self.class.name!r} object")

There are some other approaches like using pool.apply_async but they are not waiting for all the methods to complete exiting immediately. When I add job.wait() along with pool.apply_async its waiting for all threads to complete but I want to print result of the thread as and when its complete.

the error we get when we run your code is along the lines of NameError: name 'class1_obj1' is not defined, https://godbolt.org/z/EYsfa4EGW , write a minimal example

certain objects are not easily transferred to another process (think file handles, pipes, sockets, etc..), and containing those things as attributes of a class makes it impossible to send the class instance to the child process in order to execute its method. You can customize the serialization and de-serialization of your class by defining the __getstate__ and __setstate__ methods if you know better how to re-construct the object (IE: certian attrs can be re-constructed rather than copied directly).

As it was explalined in previous comments you can't pass any custom class into new processes. Thus you need implement ways to deserialise an object  and serialize it again. One of the solutions to consider will be to create json from the class, pass jsons into pool.map and then create new class instance from the given json.

Can you give example link ? @JohnnyCheesecutter

Also consider using Pool from pathos module: from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool It uses dill instead of pickle and thus can handle pickling better.

on a side note, please include the relevant import statements as part of your code snippet, so that your example is actually reproducible. (in this case, the import of the Pool class)

@JohnnyCheesecutter i have tried that earlier, but no luck

@jsbueno Done, updated

Your question is somewhat vague. If push_wrapper is expecting to be passed a class instance that has been instantiated by the main process, which seems to be the case looking at the code, but you want the method calls to push be done in parallel, then:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A.__init__ called')

    def push(self):
        print('A.push called')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('B.__init__ called')

    def push(self):
        print('B.push called')

def push_wrapper(class_instance):
    class_instance.push()

def main():
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    class_instances = [A(), B()]

    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(push_wrapper, class_instances)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
A.__init__ called
B.__init__ called
A.push called
B.push called

But this does not fit the description you provided in English, namely:

All these methods should execute in parallel

So, if you would really like to do both the class instantiation followed by a call to push in parallel (i.e. "all these methods"), then you can pass to your worker function the name of the class as follows:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A.__init__ called')

    def push(self):
        print('A.push called')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('B.__init__ called')

    def push(self):
        print('B.push called')


def create_class_instance(class_name, *args, **kwargs):
    the_class = globals()[class_name]
    return the_class(*args, **kwargs)

def push_wrapper(class_name):
    class_instance = create_class_instance(class_name)
    class_instance.push()

def main():
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    class_names = ['A', 'B']

    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(push_wrapper, class_names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
A.__init__ called
A.push called
B.__init__ called
B.push called

Another Way by Passing Class Types
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A.__init__ called')

    def push(self):
        print('A.push called')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('B.__init__ called')

    def push(self):
        print('B.push called')


def create_class_instance(class_type, *args, **kwargs):
    return class_type(*args, **kwargs)
    # Or return class_type.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

def push_wrapper(class_type):
    class_instance = create_class_instance(class_type)
    class_instance.push()

def main():
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    class_types = [A, B]

    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(push_wrapper, class_types)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
A.__init__ called
A.push called
B.__init__ called
B.push called

And If You Are Possibly Specifying a Class Name In Another Package/Module
We assume that each class implements an append method:
class A:
    def __init__(self, l=None):
        self.l = l or []

    def append(self, value):
        self.l.append(value)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f'A({self.l})'

def create_class_instance(package_class_name, *args, **kwargs):
    parts = package_class_name.split('.')
    l = len(parts)
    if l != 1:
        package_name = '.'.join(parts[0:l-1])
        class_name = parts[-1]
        module = __import__(package_name, globals(), locals(), [class_name])
        return module.__dict__[class_name](*args, *kwargs)
    return globals()[package_class_name](*args, **kwargs)

def append_wrapper(package_class_name, *args, **kwargs):
    class_instance = create_class_instance(package_class_name, *args, **kwargs)
    class_instance.append(4)
    print(class_instance)

def main():
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    class_names_and_args = [
        ('A', [1, 2, 3]),
        ('collections.deque', [1, 2, 3]),
        ('array.array', 'i', [1, 2, 3])
    ]

    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(append_wrapper, class_names_and_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
A([1, 2, 3, 4])
deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
array('i', [1, 2, 3, 4])


Thanks , this worked. Can you explain why passing class instances to pool.map doesn't work where as passing classnames to pool.map working ?

Sorry about that: I had meant to show also another way passing class types (not instances). I have updated the answer. Depending on whether you have a class type or class name, you would use one technique or the other.

You want to pass the workers instances of your classes, and then have they call the push method of each. Classes are not serializable (Python internally uses the stdlib's pickle for that), and can't be passed as arguments to the workers.
On the other hand, intances of a regular class can be passed around (note that special classes created by extensions in native code might not have pickle support - but that can be implemented - check the pickle protocol docs) - and then, all the workers need to do is to call the push method on each.
TL;DR: you should get it working changing  the wrapper, and the map single line:
...
def push_wrapper(push_callable):
    return push_callable()
...
with Pool(...) as pool:
    pool.map(push_wrapper, (cls().push for cls in class_objects))
...

Note that the expression (cls().push for cls in class_objects) is a generator expression - therefore an iterable which is acceptable by pool.map - and for each element in your class's sequence, creates an instance (cls()), and references its .push method as the target callable to be run in the worker.
Under the hood, subprocessing (or any drop-in library) will serialize the instance just created (if you need a reference to instance in the root process, modify the code as you want), along with a reference to its push method.

Thanks. pool.map(push_wrapper, (cls.push() for cls in class_objects)) worked when i use cls().push , i am getting 'ClasName' object is not callable. But what i observed it these push methods are not running in parallel

I don't get it. If class_objects contain instances of classes that implements the push method, then your generator expression is generating the results of having called push on each instance and it is those results that are being passed to worker function push_wrapper, which is probably getting an exception. That is, the actual call to push is being performed by the main process serially as the generator expression generates its results. The OP has also not specified a [mre].

My generator expression is not performing a call to each  push method. It would
be doing so if it where written (cls().push() for cls in class_objects) , but in the code above, there are no () after push -the parentheses in Python are the "operator" which trigger a method (or function  - more strictly, a "callable")  call. Without those I have a reference to the bound method.

@Booboo But, indeed, for this to work with map I need a fixed, "picklable" callable - I updated the answer to include such a pass-through wrapper that can work with map.

I need to get new eye glasses :-)

@Booboo - by coincidence, I just came across this post, today,  in a newsletter I subscribe: https://asim.bearblog.dev/how-a-single-chatgpt-mistake-cost-us-10000/  - guess what was the mistake? :-)
